# Is returning a longer array allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, output

There exist some questions that it's easier to output an array longer than intended to output, and it costs to slice.

Longer array behave like small ones as long as you don't access its length or out-of-range values, and for languages like C, `malloc` in lots of libs allocate more memory.

So for languages that `length` exists, Is returning a longer array allowed?

Comment: It would make a better question if you have a concrete example (challenge and answer) where such output method is golfier. If you're thinking in the line of [this challenge of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/224945/78410) and you want to skip "take first n" part, then the answer is: no, I won't allow it.

Comment: I don't quite understand your edit. If a language supports an array or a list object, there will definitely be a length property attached to it. And an array/list having n+extra elements cannot be equal to an array having n elements. Therefore such output is not allowed. And IMO the whole question doesn't make sense without mentioning [tag:sequence]. Why did you edit it out?

Comment: @Bubbler Also notice real programming may use longer array to reduce resizing

Comment: If a challenge says "Output the first \$n\$ elements of this array" and your answer outputs the first \$2n\$ elements (or however more than the question says), then arguably it falls under [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9447/66833) standard loophole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

#### Data structure view

Vector is a fundamental data structure for a growable, indexable array. It is commonly known that, when the allocated buffer space needs to grow, it is reallocated with twice the previous size (so that "push" operation is kept at amortized O(1)). Therefore, the allocated buffer will be longer than the length (the number of actual elements) most of the time.

**But**, it should be noted that the `length` property *is* what defines the content of the vector. Let's assume the buffer contains the values `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. If the `length` is 4, the vector object as a whole represents an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. If it is 3, the object represents an array `[1, 2, 3]`.

They. Are. Not. Equal.

In order to be able to consider two objects the same, the expected behavior should be the same *for all defined operations*. Let's again consider the `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[1, 2, 3]` case. Accessing the indices 0 to 2 is not the only operations allowed on it.

- The most obvious one is requesting the length. The former will return 4 while the latter will return 3.
- If an out-of-bounds index is requested, it should result in an error. But accessing index 3 of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` does not error.

> Longer array behave like small ones as long as you don't access its length or out-of-range values

To achieve this effect, you should re-assign the length yourself (or equivalent in your language of choice). `[1, 2, 3, 4]` resized into length 3 *is* identical to `[1, 2, 3]`, even if the 4 is still in the memory.

If you're working in C or a lower-level language, writing `n+extra` items into the given buffer and returning `n` is a valid method to effectively return an array of length `n`. (Remember, a buffer *and* length combined defines an array. Also note that something of an array type (e.g. `int [3]`) cannot be passed as an argument to or returned from a function.)

#### Software engineering view

Have you seen "test cases" on many challenges? They define a *unit test* which every submission shall pass. Unit tests for arrays (and nested structures) compare the `actual` and `expected` values via **deep equality**. Deep equality of two arrays `x` and `y` is defined as follows:

- **The length of `x` is equal to that of `y`**, and
- `x[i] == y[i]` for every valid index `i`.

If your submission outputs a longer array than requested, it violates the first condition of deep equality, and therefore it fails the unit test. What do you get if a unit test fails? A big red cross, a.k.a. "Sorry, your submission is invalid, and should be deleted."

Comment: So do C answers returning array need to return length?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes. Returning a constant array `[1, 2, 3]` would look like `int f(int*o){o[0]=1;o[1]=2;o[2]=3;return 3;}` where `o` is a pointer to the output buffer provided by the caller.